# 3 SVG's on the same page

Tags: animation, svg

I'm trying to display 3 animated svg's on the homepage of our future website.
When animating the each svg separately (each on a single page) it works fine.

But, when animating them on the same page, they don't render prorperly, as the second svg displays some elements of the first one, and same thing for the third one taking elements from the second one.

I'm guessing it's due to the name of different masks, but I've tried renaming them, and the problem still happens.

I'm running out of solutions. Is there a SVG expert out there then can help? That would be super cool. Thank you!

Here is a test page with the 3 svg's. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1699508/index.html

Each SVG has 3 states:

1. State 1 is "S0" on page-1
2. State 2 is "S0 SAnimStart" on page-1
3. State 3 is "S1 visible" on page-2

Thank you all :)

Comment: Your testpage consists only the svg and the keyframes animations, but is there some script missing? I cannot see any animation.

Answer (score 1):

All SVGs are part of the HTML-DOM and all keyframe definitions too. And so there is a multiple use of **ids**, for instance `id="page-1"`. Use unique ids or bind your animations on the css classes of the layers.